# How do I fetch a single field from a mysql query in one line with php?

Tags: php, mysql

php and mysql...

the query:

```
$sql = "SELECT keyterm
        FROM keyterms
        WHERE keyterm_id = $keyterm_id";

$result = mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql); // returns a single result
```

fetch results:

```
$keyterm = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$keyterm = $keyterm["keyterm"];
```

what is the equivalent of the last two lines in a single line?

Comment: $keyterm = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); $keyterm = $keyterm["keyterm"]; :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [`fetch_object()`](http://www.php.net/mysqli-result.fetch-object) because PHP allows you to chain the `->`operator directly onto the return value of a function, which you cannot do with the `[ ]` operator.

```
$keyterm = $result->fetch_object()->keyterm;
```

Or, procedural style:

```
$keyterm = mysqli_fetch_object($result)->keyterm;
```

Answer (score 2):

[`extract()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) (**take care**):

```
extract(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
```

You will get a warning when `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` returns FALSE (non-array). **Field/Column name must be named as the variable.**

Edit: Made it bold as some might have not read that.

Comment: -1 This is downright dangerous and can cause weird bugs if the schema was to change, a new variable introduced or any other factor. Don't!

Comment: Hmm, you've read the take care note, haven't you? As well as the comment below which makes your comment rather redundant.

Comment: With the explicit SELECT statement three lines above an `extract` doesn't seem much of a dangerousity here.

Comment: @phant0m: If the schema changes the query fails.

Comment: Still, `extract()` in this context seems limited in its usefulness, especially when there are much more broadly applicable solutions.

Comment: Yes, please see phantOms answer. It's far more accessible.

Comment: You are right, *here* it's not *that* bad, but I wouldn't expect him/her to limit its usage to this specific query ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you only fetch a single column, you can also use:

```
 $keyterm = current(mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

Works since PHP5. It just gets the first entry from the array (whether indexed or associative), and assigns it to the variable. That's the cheapest option here.